Help calculating the apparent size of moons in orbit
I have three moons I am contending with for this planet. There exact size and mass I am still working out. Right now, I am trying to find an equation that will let me know how big a moon would appear to the naked eye based on the moon's size and distance from the planet.
Other notes: The planet in question can be treated as Earth analogue.

This is one of the most frequently asked questions here on worldbuilding. A search, either on Internet or just on the existing questions, would have given you the answer immediately.

@L.Dutch Well... I tried searching on here and the general internet. I couldn't find what I was looking for, that's why I asked. I'm guessing I just didn't know the right sort of terminology to find it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Maybe you didn't notice since you are new here: when you type the title of the question you get already suggested similar questions. The duplicate one is the first in the list as soon as you type "apparent size"

What you're looking for is the equations that describe angular diameter, for a massive (therefore spherical) moon you'll need to use:
δ=2arcsin(dact/2D)
Where dact is the actual diameter of the object and D is the distance to it's centre from the point of observation. δ will be in degrees.

δ will be in degrees, or gons, or radians depending on what arcsin returns on your calculator. In any self-respecting programming language arcsin returns radians.

@AlexP δ will always be in degrees using that formula raw, if you want it in anything else then you have to do a post calculation process, yes most number crunching programs do that automatically a graphics calculator will return a raw result in degrees, mine defaults to degrees, minutes and seconds I have to switch to get decimal and convert for Radians.

Or just use arcsin(x) = sin(x) = x for x<<1

.. and I just noticed the "will be in degrees" part, and the doubling down in the comments. Small angle approximation will not hold in degrees, for reasons that are hopefully obvious. Anyway, AlexP is correct.
